# sql query to calculate the stock of each product from table of sells and table the purchases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables :

First table is called `tbpurchase` for purchased items looks like:

```
|id | Product | quantity |
+---+---------+----------+
 1  | Hp i5   | 20
 2  | Acer i7 | 10
```

The second table is for sales for sold items and looks like

```
|id | Product | quantity |
+---+---------+----------+
 1  | Hp i5   | 5
 2  | Acer i7 | 2
```

I don't know how to query the stock which still available for each product

Thanks in advance

I would really appreciate your effort

Comment: is the id unique for the product or is it just the name?

Comment: the id is unique for each product , please help, thanks for your effort

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 2):

`UNION ALL` the tables. Use negative quantity for sold items. `GROUP BY` the result and `SUM()`:

```
select id, Product, sum(quantity) quantity 
from 
(
    select id, Product,  quantity from tbpurchase
    union all
    select id, Product, -quantity from tbsold
) dt
group by id, Product
```

Comment: thanks a billion it worked for me, but still have an issue when the query calculate, the column name of the quantity : (no column name)  , normaly it shoud give : quantity

Comment: Fixed, simply added the column name/alias after the SUM().

Comment: I wanted the ask another question for vb.net but I got the message : Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more. does it mean that I can't ask anymore forever?

Comment: I have no idea. Perhaps you're expected to accept the best answer to this question...

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a `correlated subquery`

```
select product, 
       sum(quantity-(select quantity from sales b where a.product = b.product)) as qty
from purchase a 
group by product;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the products are unique in each table (as in the sample data), you can just use a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(p.product, s.product) as product,
       coalesce(p.quantity, 0) - coalesce(s.quantity, 0) as in_stock
from tbpurchase p full join
     tbsale s
     on p.product = s.product;
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to total up from both tables the values -- so to get the total sold you would do this

```
select product, sum(quantity) as tot_pur
from tbpurchase 
group by product
```

similar for sold

```
select product, sum(quantity) as tot_solepur
from tbsold
group by product
```

Then join them together and do the math

```
select p.product, p.tot_pur - s.tot_sol as cur_on_hand
from (
  select product, sum(quantity) as tot_pur
  from tbpurchase
  group by product 
) as p 
join (
  select product, sum(quantity) as tot_sol
  from tbsold
  group by product
) as s on p.product = s.product
```